# Armpit: sobaco vs. axila

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos, vocabulario

"Armpit" in English can be translated as either *sobaco* or *axila* in Spanish. Is each term used in different regions, or are they both used across the Spanish-speaking world? What is the difference, or are they exact synonyms? If they are synonyms, which is more common?

Comment: I agree that sobaco is more informal and somewhat "vulgar", and axila is a more proper name. BTW, sobaco (or the word that sounds like it) means "dog" in Russian - probably just a coincidence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

| Country | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | *Sobaco* is much more informal, almost vulgar. You'd never hear it in a deodorant ad, or in medical speak. |
| Bolivia | *Sobaco* is really vulgar. Better use *axila*. |
| Chile | *Sobaco* is also almost vulgar and very informal. |
| Colombia | *Sobaco* is also almost vulgar and very informal. |
| Cuba | In Cuba we use both *Axila* and *Sobaco*. *Sobaco* is more informal than *Axila*. |
| Dominican Republic | *Sobaco* has the same meaning and connotations that in other Spanish speaking countries. *Axila* is the more ethical and formal, while *sobaco* is more informal. |
| Ecuador | *Sobaco* is more informal, I think it is better to say "axila". |
| Mexico | *Sobaco* is vulgar and if you do use it, it is when someone has bad odor in their armpits (*te huele el sobaco*, *hueles a sobaco*). *Axila* is when you are actually referring to the armpit as a body part. |
| Panama | *Axila* is the word that we use to refer to the armpit. *Sobaco* is used for people from the "Guetto". |
| Peru | *Sobaco* is not very used, the usual form is *axila* for both formal and informal situations. |
| Spain | *Sobaco* is more informal than *axila*. |
| Venezuela | *Sobaco* is more informal yet used by the upper class. *Axila* is used in medical contexts. |

Comment: "Sobaco" is more informal, I think it is better to say "axila" (at least in Ecuador).

Comment: In Panama city, "axila" is the word that we use to refer to the armpit. "Sobaco" is used for people from the "Guetto"

Comment: In Mexico it applies the same as in other countries. "Sobaco" is vulgar and if you do use it, its when someone has bad odor in their armpits (te huele el sobaco, hueles a sobaco). Axila is when you are actually referring to the armpit as a body part.

Comment: In Bolivia "sobaco" is really vulgar. Do not use it there. Way better to say "axila", for both humans and animals (even though the term is rarely used in animals).

Comment: Algún otro español puede corroborarme que en España la palabra sobaco es la mas usada en cualquier entorno que no necesite ser puramente formal?

Comment: In Nicaragua and Honduras, I'll add that sobaco is very informal. It's not a street slang (jerga), but it is incredibly rare that one would see it in written, formal word or spoken by cultured, highbrow people. 

It is not vulgar, but it would be extremely out of place to use it in formal speech.

When used, it's almost in a derogatory sense (either to describe bad odor to that part of the body, or to indicate that the person possessing it is not someone you care much about.)

When in doubt, use axila (in Nicaragua, or in general.)

Comment: @luis.espinal cool! Feel free to edit the answer: we made it community wiki to allow that passing-by visitors like you can improve it! Many thanks

Comment: @jacobo genial la adaptación a tablas, buena idea. En [esta respuesta en Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674) a _Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers_ puedes encontrar una buena lista de las que tienen este formato.

Comment: In Spain, "sobaco" is much more used than "axila" when speaking. "Axila" is used on TV, formal writing, medicine and such.

Answer (score 16):

In Colombia both forms are used about equally. I prefer axila since is a more technical term and sobaco is perhaps used more often when referring to animals. There's a Colombian saying that goes like this:

> Estoy más pelado que sobaco de rana (I don't have a dime on me.)

Again, sobaco is more colloquial and axila is more formal/technical and they refer to the same part of the body on both, animals and humans.

In the Dominican Republic, *sobaco* is also used to refer to someone with bad odor on his armpit. [See this dictionary of Dominicanismos by Colonial Tour and Travel](http://www.colonialtours.com.do/diccionario.htm)

If you visit the Dominican Republic and someone tells you "tú tienes sobaco," is very likely that the person isn't referring to your body parts but rather urging you to take a shower and get a hold of a deodorant as soon as possible.

In several countries the word sobaco is considered vulgar and unsophisticated.

Comment: +1 in Spain "sobaco" is also more informal than "axila". The armpit of the animals is not a very common topic of conversation here so I don't really know if we would say "sobaco" for it :D

Comment: In Perú sobaco is not very used, the usual form is axila for both, formal and informal situations.

Comment: In Argentina "sobaco" is much more informal, almost vulgar. You'd never hear it in a deodorant ad, or in medical speak.

Comment: In Chile "sobaco" is also almost vulgar and very informal.

Comment: It seems that "sobaco" has a connotation of vulgarity everywhere.

Comment: The comment regarding the Dominican Republic is incorrect. "Sobaco" has the same meaning and connotations that in other Spanish speaking countries. "Axila" is the more ethical and formal, while "sobaco" is more informal.

Comment: I m sorry to disagree. In Colombia they are not used "about equally". It is exactly the same as in other counties mentioned. _Sobaco_ is vulgar and you will never heard an educated person saying it except on the idiom "más pelado que sobaco de rana". _Axila_ is the more commonly used word in an "educated" context.