# ¿Tiene algún nombre la unión entre el cuerpo de una camisa y sus mangas?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, ropa

Supongamos que estamos diseñando una camisa.

- Empezamos construyendo lo que vendría a ser el cuerpo, el talle y tenemos una especie de chaleco.
- En paralelo fabricamos unas mangas.
- Finalmente juntamos esas mangas al *chaleco* por lo que vendrían a ser los tirantes.

A partir de este momento los tirantes ya no son tales, sino que representan el inicio de la manga, que vendría ser lo que rodea el sobaco (o axila, pues [cada cual lo dice de una manera según el país](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18186/1674)) de la persona que lo lleva. ¿Recibe algún nombre ese espacio interior, hueco o vano, que conecta el cuerpo con la manga? Podría entender que se llamara *junta* a esa unión, pero no se me ocurre más.

Comment: Me parece que se llama "sisa".

Comment: @Gustavson caramba, ¡esa es! Además, acabo de entender la expresión _me tira de la sisa_ :) Pues si te animas, ponlo como respuesta y así constará en acta. Curioso por cierto, que en España digamos _sisar_ a _robar_...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hacia el final de la página [Tomando Medidas a tu Camisa Favorita](http://www.camisasdevestir.com/2010/09/tomando-medidas-tu-camisa-favorita.html) puede observarse que la unión del cuerpo y la manga en una prenda de vestir se denomina "sisa":

> **sisa**
>
> [image]
>
> Asegúrese de que la parte delantera de la camisa es hacia arriba. Coloque la cinta métrica en la parte superior de la costura de la sisa y seguir la costura a lo largo de su borde hasta el punto donde se reúne la sisa con la manga. Mida cuidadosamente ya que esta es una línea curva.

Comment: También puedes ver imágenes googleando *corte y confección sisa*.  Por si te interesa, en inglés es *armsceye* o *armseye*.

Comment: También lo puedes comprobar con la [definición del DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y1Vjmk7): "Corte curvo hecho en el cuerpo de una prenda de vestir que corresponde a la parte de la axila".